# snapshot on C# (without monitor or even graphic card installed)

Tags: c#, screenshot

I'm trying to record all what happens in my little program(video and audio). I've found on forums people mentioning that there can be a big problem if screenshot is made on the machine without monitor - no monitor physically connected or when graphics card places monitor in sleep mode or even without graphics card installed (servers). is there a way to solve this issue? currently i haven't access to server and even don't know it's configuration(((

currently i'm using this code to make snapshots every 50 milliseconds and it's works great on desktop pc(can't check this code without monitor... i'm using HP touchsmart monoblock desktop)

```
            IntPtr myIntptr = FormElement.Handle;
            int hwndInt = myIntptr.ToInt32();
            IntPtr hwnd = myIntptr;
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(FormElement.Width, FormElement.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
            bool result = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, 0);
            g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            g.Flush();
            if (result == true)
            {
                bm.Save(aFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
```

this doent work if i minimize my window and this is not good too.

sorry for my english and thanx for any advice.

Comment: The version of windows(and if you're using Aero or not) might be relevant.

Comment: currently i'm using win7 and vista, but this code will be used on WinServer2003. i've testet code in VmWare WinServer2003 and it works great, but on the real servers graphic cards are really rare.

Comment: I don't think 2003 can work without a graphic card... But what really matters is what you want to capture when nothig is rendered. Specifying it would made answering easier for people.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public static void ScreenCapture(string filename, int width, int height)
{
    var bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(
            new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size
        );
        bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```